# How to create class variable in module?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I have module

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def m(val)
      # todo
    end
  end
end
```

And I have class

```
class A
  include M
end
```

Method `m` from `module M` must push `val` in class variable `arr` when I call it.

```
A.m(1)
A.m(2)
A.m(3)
A.arr # => [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I do it properly?

I have solution below, but I don't sure it the best.

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :arr
    def m (val)
      self.arr ||= []
      arr << val
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The question is: Is host class expected to have `arr` or your module will bring it along? If it's the latter, then your code is fine. Only don't use attr_accessor and go for explicit getter/setter instead (since you need the lazy-initializing getter)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, like this `def arr; @arr ||= []; end` or `def arr; @@arr ||= []; end`

Comment: The first option, `@arr ||= []`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, but both work properly. What is the difference?

Comment: `@@arr` will be visible in subclasses, for example. You don't want that usually.

Comment: very interesting, thanks

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, one more question, how to get rid of lazy-initializing?

Comment: Why get rid of lazy-initializing?

Comment: it's interesting for me how to initialize variable previously

Comment: Well, seeing that you don't have a initializer/constructor here, there's not much you can do about it.